# Sliding Text when overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't want to choose among options that flutter proposes when the text overflows. In fact, I want the text to slide from the right when overflowing to reveal the whole text (as highlighted in the attached picture).

Here is my code on the specified section of the app I am working on:

```
class PlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayerScreenState createState() => _PlayerScreenState();
}



class _PlayerScreenState extends State<PlayerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
   
      ...
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: [
                     // Some previous code here             
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Sermon Name Here',
                          style: kMainStyling.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                          maxLines: 1,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 150,
                          child: Text(
                            'Pastor\'s Name Here',
                            maxLines: 1,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: kMainStyling.copyWith(
                              color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(.8),
                            ),
                            overflow: TextOverflow
                                .ellipsis, 
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
              );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't see any attached file

Comment: Sorry, here is the link !! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r1B5zeEuA2l8Hf9TkdoUUjM-VXweTqa5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: restricted access

Comment: Access granted !!

Comment: Restricted access

Answer (score 0):

Simply Wrap your text widget with a SingleChildScrollView widget and set the scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

Comment: Adding some code as example would improve this answer a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Text widget with a SingleChildScrollView and set the scrollDirection to horizontal, The code will look like this.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Text(
    'Sermon Name Here',
    style: kMainStyling.copyWith(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    maxLines: 1,
  ),
)
```